# Arrows and boxes to decorate table

Tags: tables, tikz-arrows

I tried replicating [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/) but when I try to put nodes inside a table like so:

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test}

    \tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]

    \begin{table}[t]
        \label{tab:test}
        \centering
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            Col1 & Col2 \\\hline
            \tikz[baseline]{
                \node (t3)
            {\alert<3>{$2^0$}};} & \alert<3>{0} \\
            $2^{1}$ & 1 \\
            $2^{2}$ & 2 \\
            $2^{3}$ & 3 \\
            $2^{4}$ & 4 \\
            $2^{5}$ & \alert<2>{5} \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
```

The table layout in the second column somehow falls apart.
How do I do this properly?

I'm not sure it will work but [here](https://www.overleaf.com/9188091dxvrmhzfvvhs) is a link for playing around.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `\tikz[baseline=(t3.base)]`, so that the `t3` node is placed correctly on the baseline of the table row. You may also want to set the `inner sep` of the node to zero.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test}

    \tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]

    \begin{table}[t]
        \label{tab:test}
        \centering
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            Col1 & Col2 \\\hline
            \tikz[baseline=(t3.base)]{
                \node [inner sep=0pt](t3)
            {\alert<3>{$2^0$}};} & \alert<3>{0} \\
            $2^{1}$ & 1 \\
            $2^{2}$ & 2 \\
            $2^{3}$ & 3 \\
            $2^{4}$ & 4 \\
            $2^{5}$ & \alert<2>{5} \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]